# Why does CSSTransitionGroup throw render error on React Router Link element?

Tags: reactjs, react-router

Why am I getting this error while trying to set a `CSSTransitionGroup` on a `react-router` `Link` component:

```
invariant.js:44 Uncaught Error: link is a void element tag and must neither have `children` nor use `dangerouslySetInnerHTML`. Check the render method of TransitionGroup.
```

My code is:

```
return (

        <CSSTransitionGroup component='Link' transitionName='navBarLink' transitionEnterTimeout={300} transitionLeaveTimeout={500}>
            <Link style={linkStyle} to={this.props.pageTo} onClick={this.setActiveState}>
                {this.props.title}
            </Link>
        </CSSTransitionGroup>

    )
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you import Link? If so why is Link in quotes

```
 component='Link'
```

Shouldn't it be

```
 component=Link
```

Comment: Both of those and `component={Link}` or `component={'Link'}` throw the same error. If I delete `component` all together it renders. Which doesn't make sense to me because in other instances that attribute is required for the animation to run.